# Highlight certain letters in words

Tags: support, layout

How exactly can I highlight certain letters in words? I recently answered a question where I wanted to highlight the starting letters of 3 words. I finally had to put in spaces so the letters appear bold. Just as an example:

**T**his doesn't work

**T** his does but it looks pretty ugly.

*S*ame goes for italic

*S* ee?

It also doesn't work in a w**o**rd.

Again I'd need to use sp **a** ces

I know it's a rather minor thing, but i often feel like highlighting certain letters can be useful in gaming related context (especially with all those abbreviations).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use HTML markup in the rare case where Markdown doesn't function.

**L**ike *t*his.

<sup>That's so ugly I can't stand that I wrote it.</sup>

Which is:

```
<b>L</b>ike <i>t</i>his.

<sup>That's so ugly I can't stand that I wrote it.</sup>
```

Comment: Upvoted for accuracy, downvoted for ugliness.